# How to create two thumbnails with django?

Tags: python, django

I want to create two thumbnails (a small one and a medium one)

This is my code (using python2.7+django1.3):

```
import Image
...
def thumbnail(f,file_name,path):
    small = 35,35
    small_file_name = path+'/small_'+file_name
    medium = 310,235
    medium_file_name = path+'/medium_'+file_name

    small_im = Image.open(f)
    small_im.thumbnail(small)
    small_im.save(small_file_name)

    medium_im = Image.open(f)
    medium_im.thumbnail(medium)
    medium_im.save(medium_file_name)
```

I am getting this error:

```
IOError at /upload/
cannot identify image file
```

`f` is image FILES post from another page, `f = request.FILES['photo']`

Some errors in last three lines, I have to comment last three lines,it's not a error, but this is not what I want.

If I run the code in the python shell it doesn't raise errors:

```
>>> from users.upload import thumbnail
>>> import Image
>>> f = '/home/david/1.jpg'
>>> file_name = 'test.jpg'
>>> path = '/home/david'
>>> thumbnail(f,file_name,path)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting an error.

Comment: Have you tried using an existing solution instead, e.g. Sorl thumbnails? Rolling your own in such cases is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem because `f = request.FILES['photo']` is not a file path, as you assume it is. Instead it is a Django [`UploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile). You should write this file to the disk somewhere before passing its path to PIL `Image.open()`.

You could also try passing the [`temporary_file_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.temporary_file_path).

Comment: but i can upload image and create small thumbnail,it's a error when second time Image.open(f).if i comment last three lines it's not error. i am confused that create first thumbnail it's ok but second have error.

Comment: Hmm, can you post your model? Are you using `upload_to` on your `ImageField`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
def thumbnail(f,file_name,path):
 img = Image.open(f)
 small = 35,35
 small_file_name = path+'/small_'+file_name
 medium = 310,235
 medium_file_name = path+'/medium_'+file_name

 img.thumbnail(medium)
 img.save(medium_file_name)

 img.thumbnail(small)
 img.save(small_file_name)
```